# Ruby on Rails with Postgis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I want to create a table in my postgres db, with one column which is a multipolgyon. How do i do that?

What i do fails because of this: 
`undefined method multipolygon for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLTableDefinition:0x4ac6f70>`:

Using this Migration:

```
class CreateBezirkes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bezirkes do |t|
      t.string :NameK
      t.integer :BezNr
      t.string :Bez_Rz
      t.string :Namek_Num
      t.string :Namek_Rz
      t.string :NameG
      t.string :Label
      t.integer :Bez
      t.integer :District_Code
      t.integer :StatAustria_Bez_Code
      t.integer :StatAustria_Gem_Code
      t.float :Flaeche
      t.float :Umfang
      t.timestamp :Akt_Timestamp
      t.multipolygon :Koordinaten
      t.integer :main_id
    end
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE bezirkes
          ADD CONSTRAINT fk_bezirkes_mains
          FOREIGN KEY (main_id)
          REFERENCES mains(id)
    SQL
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the [postgis gem](https://github.com/dazuma/activerecord-postgis-adapter). It is based on [Rgeo](https://github.com/dazuma/rgeo), which provides some nice spatial methods.

Otherwise just do:

```
 t.column :koordinaten, :multipolygon
```

note: your column names should not begin with a capital letter, according to rails conventions.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  `activerecord-postgis-adapter` version 0.6.2.  What version are you running?

Comment: sorry, i'm not running this anymore (this was on my previous job...). Is postgis well installed ?

Comment: Yea, I can run all the other `postgis` commands and `points` and `polygons` work just fine.  In the meantime, I just run a manual `AddGeomColumn` in my migration to take care of the `multipolygon`.

Comment: Weird. just to be sure, did you change the adapter from `postgres` to `postgis` in `database.yml` ? otherwise, do other features from Rgeo work with your technique ? note : maybe this changed in recent versions of the gem. I see it is still well maintained (it has support for rails 4)

Comment: Yep, the adapter is set to `postgis` and that line is configured in `application.rb`.  I also noticed that the gem is actively maintained and have found some other tutorials and tricks that no longer work, but for the most part the other `rgeo` features work just fine.  Don't know if the exclusion of `multipolygon` was intentional or not.

Comment: I think for now your best option is to - gasp - read the gem's source.

Comment: Stumbled across this on a blog written by Daniel: it's now called `multi_polygon` (notice the underscore).  Seems to work now.  Gotta love syntax.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's confirm you have installed [activerecord-postgis-adapter](https://github.com/dazuma/activerecord-postgis-adapter) gem, and you Postgresql database is properly configured with postgis (as per [this tutorial](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ch02.html)). I would like to stress that postgis installation is per-schema, not global, so having it installed in schema A doesn't mean it will be installed for any other schemas on the same machine.

Next, it looks like some versions of the postgit adapter do not have a method to create multipolygon columns (at least mine does not), so you have 2 options: go with geomerty/geography column (you will have corresponding methods, but lose data checking on PostgreSQL side) or use a generic t.column method to create a column, like:

```
t.column :Koordinaten, :multipolygon
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have your `adapter` set to `postgis` in `config/database.yml`